# SOAP in iOS Application

Tags: ios, xcode, soap

I'm trying to develop an app that uses data from a SOAP service. is the first time I use a SOAP service. After reading several tutorials I thought I would be able to set the request to the service in the right way but I always get errors in the response. What's wrong ?!

this is the code for the request

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://microsoft.com/webservices/\">\n"
"<SOAP-ENV:Body>\n"
"<ns1:ListaComuni>\n"
"<Nazione>italia</Nazione>\n"
"</ns1:ListaComuni>\n"
"</SOAP-ENV:Body>\n"
"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n"
];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxx.xxx/XXXXX.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

When i receive the answer

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"RISPOSTA %@",theXML);
}
```

The log:

```
RISPOSTA <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><ListaComuniResponse xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/"><ListaComuniResult><anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</anyType></ListaComuniResult></ListaComuniResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I tested the XML request on http://wsdlbrowser.com and it all works.
What's wrong ?!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...
i found the error...the correct request is:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                         "<soap:Body>"
                         "<ListaComuni xmlns=\"http://microsoft.com/webservices/\">"
                         "<Nazione>%@</Nazione>\n"
                         "</ListaComuni>"
                         "</soap:Body>"
                         "</soap:Envelope>", nameInput.text
 ];
```